# Pandas taking ratio of difference from the row above and store the value in another column, with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, rows, multi-index, difference

I want to know how to get the difference ratio between two rows with multiindexed columns, and store them in specific columns.

I have a dataframe which looks like this.

```
>>>df

                   A             B            C
                   total  diff   total  diff  total  diff 
  2020-08-15       100    0      200    0     20     0
```

Everyday, I add one new row. The new row looks like this.

```
df_new

                   A             B            C
                   total  diff   total  diff  total  diff 
  2020-08-16       200     -      50    -     30     -
```

And for the columns `diff`, I want to take the ratio from the row above, for the value of `total`. So the formula will be `([total of today] - [total of the day before]) / [total of the day before]`

```
                   A             B              C
                   total  diff   total  diff    total  diff 
  2020-08-15       100    0      200    0       20     0
  2020-08-16       200    1.0    50     -0.75   30     0.5
```

I know how to add a new row.

```
day = dt.today()
df.loc[day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), :] = df_new.squeeze()
```

But I don't know how I can get the difference between two rows with multiindexed columns... Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `shift` to calculate the results and update the original df:

```
s = df.filter(like="total").rename(columns={"total":"diff"}, level=1)
res = ((s - s.shift(1))/s.shift(1))
df.update(res)

print (df)

               A          B           C     
           total diff total  diff total diff
2020-08-15   100  0.0   200  0.00    20  0.0
2020-08-16   200  1.0    50 -0.75    30  0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) to update MultiIndexed values.

```
#df
#      A          B          C
#  total diff total diff total diff
#0   100    0   200    0    20    0

#df2
#       A          B          C
#   total diff total diff total diff
#0  200.0  NaN  50.0  NaN  30.0  NaN

# Take last row of current DataFrame i.e. `df`
curr = df.iloc[-1].xs('total', level=1) #Get total values
# Take total values of new DataFrame you get everyday i.e. `df2`
new = df2.iloc[0].xs('total',level=1)

# Calculate diff values
diffs = new.sub(curr).div(curr) # This is equal to `(new-curr)/curr`
idx = pd.IndexSlice
x = pd.concat([df, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)
x.loc[x.index[-1], idx[:,'diff']] = diffs.tolist()

x
       A           B           C
   total diff  total  diff total diff
0  100.0  0.0  200.0  0.00  20.0  0.0
1  200.0  1.0   50.0 -0.75  30.0  0.5
```

If you dont want to create new DataFrame(`x`), then use `DataFrame.append` to append values.

Everything is the same use until the step `idx = pd.IndexSlice`, don't create `x` but append values to `df`

```
df2.loc[:, idx[:,'diff']] = diffs.tolist()
df.append(df2)

       A           B           C
   total diff  total  diff total diff
0  100.0  0.0  200.0  0.00  20.0  0.0
0  200.0  1.0   50.0 -0.75  30.0  0.5
```